# back button on Angular2 is broken

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

UPDATED **

I'm writing my first Angular2 app using routing. A simple quiz application.

Clicking the back button triggers the problem behavior, the template does not render properly with data from the model.

I have a routing scheme where you can go between a series of questions in a quiz using a URL pattern like `/question/:n`.

My component implements `OnReuse`, `OnActivate`, and `CanReuse`.

My model is attached to the component via a property.

[This Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8LMo0VLCLIuM06itCifn) has a simplified version of my app.

You can see that clicking the Next button goes to the next question and updates the URL. Clicking the browser's back button does change the URL back, but the template does not actually render.

What am I missing?

Comment: Updated the question with a Plunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a base href issue then it is difficult to diagnose with Plunker.  So I am not sure if this is the issue, but please give it a try.

Try changing this:

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

To This:

```
 <base href="/">
```

within your index.html.  If it's already set to to the latter please comment and I will update this response.

Comment: Thanks! hmm, i tried that and it didn't have any observable change on behavior

Comment: BTW tried it in the Plunker and also my actual codebase

Comment: Definitely use the second option in your actual application.  If you use the first, then refreshing a page other than your homepage will dynamically set your base href to something you don't want.  But unfortunately, I'm have difficulty replicating the issue.  The plunker code seems to go to the next question when clicking next, holds onto the correct url/view when refreshing, and displays the correct question when using back.  Any other ideas on how we can replicate the issue?

Comment: Very interesting! It has not been working for me on Safari, but your comment prompted me to test it on Chrome, where it does work. Seems to be a browser support issue

Comment: I'll file an issue with Angular! Thanks for your help.

Comment: for anyone interested, [here is the ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7873) on the Angular repo